# Convert a Dataset[immutable.Iterable[(String, String, String)]] to Spark Dataset[(String, String, String)]

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I want to convert a **Dataset[immutable.Iterable[(String, String, String)]]** to Spark **Dataset[(String, String, String)]**.

I am getting Encoder not found errors in all combinations I try.

Please suggest how can I do it?

Below is the code snippet.

Here, the variable 'z' is of type Dataset[immutable.Iterable[(String, String, String)]].

I want Dataset[(String, String, String)]

```
val z: Dataset[immutable.Iterable[(String, String, String)]] = dataFrame.map(row => {
        val rowKeyValue = row.getAs[String](rowKeyColumn)
        row.getValuesMap[Any](validColumnsOtherThanRowKeyColumn)
          .map(mapColumnNameToValueString => {
            // println("finalColumnName:::" + finalColumnName + ":::")
            (rowKeyValue, mapColumnNameToValueString._1.toString, mapColumnNameToValueString._2.toString)
          })
      })
```

Comment: Can you change inside row.getValuesMap[Any](validColumnsOtherThanRowKeyColumn)
          .map to row.getValuesMap[Any](validColumnsOtherThanRowKeyColumn)
          .flatMap ? & check also remove datatype of z.

Comment: can you also some sample data for this to test ??

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `.toList.toDS` on `Iterable` object.

```
scala> val it = Seq(("a","b","c")).to[scala.collection.immutable.Iterable]
it: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(String, String, String)] = Vector((a,b,c))

scala> it.toList.toDS.show(false)
+---+---+---+
|_1 |_2 |_3 |
+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |c  |
+---+---+---+
```

**Updated** : Just change inside `map` to `flatMap`

```
val z: Dataset[(String, String, String)] = dataFrame.flatMap(row => {
        val rowKeyValue = row.getAs[String](rowKeyColumn)
        row.getValuesMap[Any](validColumnsOtherThanRowKeyColumn)
          .map(mapColumnNameToValueString => {
            // println("finalColumnName:::" + finalColumnName + ":::")
            (rowKeyValue, mapColumnNameToValueString._1.toString, mapColumnNameToValueString._2.toString)
          })
})
```

**or** If above is not working try below once & let me know if you get any errors or issues.

```
val z: Dataset[(String, String, String)] = dataFrame.map(row => {
        val rowKeyValue = row.getAs[String](rowKeyColumn)
        row.getValuesMap[Any](validColumnsOtherThanRowKeyColumn)
          .map(mapColumnNameToValueString => {
            // println("finalColumnName:::" + finalColumnName + ":::")
            (rowKeyValue, mapColumnNameToValueString._1.toString, mapColumnNameToValueString._2.toString)
          })
}).flatMap(d => d)
```

Comment: Edited question, please check now and suggest.

Comment: Check this now I have updated answer, Earlier I have added same in above comment.

Comment: It did not work. Cannot resolve overloaded method 'flatMap'.

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert the **immutable.Iterable** to **Seq** to avoid the Encoder issues, and it worked with the below along with flatMap at the end.

```
val z: Dataset[(String, String, String)] = dataFrame.map(row => {
        val rowKeyValue = row.getAs[String](rowKeyColumn)
        row.getValuesMap[Any](validColumnsOtherThanRowKeyColumn)
          .map(mapColumnNameToValueString => {
            (rowKeyValue, mapColumnNameToValueString._1.toString, mapColumnNameToValueString._2.toString)
          }).toSeq
      }).flatMap(x => x)
```

Thanks @Srinivas for helping on the question and flatMap solution.